# Loss is decreasing however so is accuracy for keras neural network model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

(I'm relatively new to neural networks and working with data so sorry if I'm doing something stupid.)

I'm trying to evaluate deep_mojis ability to generalise by trying to use it on different datasets. I'm using it on stanford SST-fine and trying to map the emoji scores to a sentiment score using a simple softmax network with one hidden layer.

From what I've read on the stanford SST, I should be converting a score to a vector with intervals of 0.2. for example 0.7 should go to [0,0,0,1,0].

However when I try to train the training loss and accuracy both decrease as well as the accuracy.

NN model

```py
class sst_fine_predictor:
    def build_model(self):
        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        self.model.add(layers.Dense(128,input_shape=(64, ), activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
        self.model.add(
            layers.Dense(128, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
        self.model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
        self.model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.01),
                           loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                           metrics=['accuracy'])
        return

    def __init__(self):
        self.build_model()
        self.stopper_1 = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=50)
        # self.stopper_2 = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=200)
        self.checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(SAVE_PATH, monitor='val_acc', mode='max', save_best_only=True)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.model

    def train(self, train_ins, train_outs, test_ins, test_outs, max_epochs=4000):
        history = self().fit(train_ins, train_outs, validation_data=(test_ins, test_outs), epochs=max_epochs, verbose=1,
                             callbacks=[self.stopper_1, self.checkpointer], batch_size=8117)
        return history

[accuracy graph][1][loss graph][1]
```

training_code

```py
training_data = pd.read_csv(SST_PATH + "emoji_train.csv", sep="|")
test_data = pd.read_csv(SST_PATH + "emoji_test.csv", sep="|")

train_ins = np.delete(training_data.values, [0,1,2], axis=1)
train_outs = categorize(training_data.values[:, 2], discrete)

correctly classified
test_ins = np.delete(test_data.values, [0,1,2], axis=1)
test_outs = categorize(test_data.values[:, 2], discrete)

model = sst_fine_predictor()


print("training model")
history = model.train(train_ins, train_outs, test_ins, test_outs, max_epochs=4000)
```

emoji_train.csv and test I'm quite certain has no issues and when loaded has these columns

```
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'sentence', 'sentiment_score', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
       '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17',
       '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29',
       '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41',
       '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53',
       '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63'],
      dtype='object')
```

with 0 to 63 representing the emoji scores

accuracy graph
[image: accuracy graph]

loss graph
[image: loss graph]

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why I've got 2 downvotes on this? It seems a valid question and I haven't seen it anywhere before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just in case anyone does need this in the future), I'm pretty sure the issue is that I'd set the L2 regularization too high and therefore it benefited the model to be more accurate with outputs / labels that required low weights to be found than it was to be accurate with all the training labels therefore making it decrease the overall accuracy as well as decreasing loss.

To put it simply having the regularization too high can make it so the loss function can benefit from getting certain answers wrong if they require high weights and then focus on certain answers being correct which require low weights.

(I may be wrong and if I am then please correct me, but this is my best guess and I'm fairly certain it's correct)

Answer (score 0):

When the loss is decreasing and so the accuracy you are facing with [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

you can avoid it by things like making your data bigger, [do dropout](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/) or simplifying the model. here is a good post on that: [How to prevent Overfitting in your Deep Learning Models](https://towardsdatascience.com/dont-overfit-how-to-prevent-overfitting-in-your-deep-learning-models-63274e552323).

Comment: No, decreasing loss and accuracy does not mean overfitting, this answer is misleading.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro sorry if it is misleading. But why? your loss is decreasing which means your model is getting fit on your training data but your accuracy on testing data is decreasing too. doesn't that mean your model is getting too fit on your test data?

Comment: The OP doesnt mention accuracy on test data, so I assume all metrics are on training data, from where you cannot infer overfitting. Overfit can only be detected with training and validation/test losses.

Comment: Hi OP here, again I might be being stupid but my validation loss is decreasing as well as the training loss which I thought indicates no overfitting however the accuracy for both is decreasing

Comment: Would the training graphs for loss and accuracy be of use?